# Cocos2d-iphone - Sphero Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, sphero-api

I'm trying to connect a Sphero to a Cocos2d game I'm building.  Sphero has some good [documentation](https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK#integrating-into-an-existing-project) and examples, and I can run the sample code.  I started with a cocos2d project and added the Sphero frameworks.  I am not able to get a basic command to the ball.  I believe the issue is in this function:

```
-(void)setupRobotConnection 
{
    /*Try to connect to the robot*/
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleRobotOnline) name:RKDeviceConnectionOnlineNotification object:nil];

    if ([[RKRobotProvider sharedRobotProvider] isRobotUnderControl]) 
         [[RKRobotProvider sharedRobotProvider] openRobotConnection];        

}
```

(The rest of the code is at the link) I believe that it has something to do with the NSNotificationCenter.  I am calling this code from a CCLayerColor, rather than a UIViewController like the demo does.  I get this error:

```
2012-08-25 01:54:19.738 bgmmo[1414:2d07] ERROR - opening session failed as protocol com.orbotix.robotprotocol is not declared in Info.plist
```

(This was answered in the [Sphero IOS Forum](http://forum.gosphero.com/showthread.php?926-Sphero-Cocos2d-ios))

Comment: Are you sure `setupRobotConnection` method is called?

Comment: Yes, because I added the onEnter and onExit methods and called [self appDidBecomeActive:nil] and [self appWillResignActive:nil] in them, so the methods are being called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You need to add the external accessory protocol string to your Info.plist. Edit the Info.plist for you application target and add a entry for key "Supported external accessory protocols" which will create an array enter. Add "com.orbotix.robotprotocol" as a String item in the array.